# Windows Authentication working on localhost but not on other site on IIS

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, windows-authentication

I'm trying to set up a simple html/css/js only site on my local IIS that uses Windows Authentication.

So far I just a have a c://mysite/index.html file

When I point the default IIS website (i.e http://localhost) to this folder and enable Windows Authentication, I am shown the login dialog when I browse to it.  When I enter my creds it then shows the index.html fine.  But when I setup a new IIS site (e.g http://local.mysite  I have a host entry for this) pointing to the same folder, with Windows Authentication enabled, I cannot get passed the login dialog. It just redisplays as if the login creds were wrong, but I'm entering the same creds as I did in http://localhost.

I have added http://local.mysite  to the local intranet zone in Internet Options, but this doesn't resolve the issue.
I have also set the application pool of local.mysite  to be the same as localhost

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer.
Issue is the loopback check security feature that's in Windows.

Fix for this can be found here  https://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;896861support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;896861

Comment: The provided link is no longer valid.

Comment: You find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402381/receiving-login-prompt-using-integrated-windows-authentication?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The original accepted answer unfortunately references an article that no longer exists.

This article contains a step-by-step fix for the issue - it might even be the originally referenced article at a new location.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37337.disable-loopback-check-in-iis.aspx

To sum it up, you need to set the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa` value `DisableLoopbackCheck` to a `DWORD` of value `1`

Check your current value i Powershell:

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa" -Name DisableLoopbackCheck
```

This should return

```
1
```