# mvc 5 active directory validation and information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory

In VS2013 I created a MVC 5 project where I chose  Authentication as "Windows Authentication".

Now when I run the application, I get an automatic popup windows to logon to windows.

Here are my questions.

1. How can I avoid automatic login popup window on launch and have my own login screen.
2. How can I get list of active directory accounts and groups.
3. How can I validate if given name is valid account or groups.
4. How can I get list of roles.

I tried searching online , but unfortunately not successful.

Thank You

Comment: Search harder, I did this a few months back and there was plenty of information online. You should NOT use WindowsAuthentication if you don't want the popup. Just use forms authentication and add your own logic for testing username/password (which will query AD)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiving login prompt using integrated windows authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402381/receiving-login-prompt-using-integrated-windows-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

For #1...

This is usually primarily a function of the zone security settings in IE. If you add your app's URL to the Local Intranet Zone in IE, you should get the desired behavior.

Specifically, if you look under Custom Level and scroll all the way to the bottom under User Authentication\Logon, you'll see the different settings for each zone.

For the others, I'd suggest perhaps a separate question for each with what you've tried.