# Randomly getting a login prompt

Tags: iis

I am randomly getting a login prompt asking me to log in to localhost:3000 while working on my project (in localhost). Sometimes it does not show up the whole day and next morning I get 10 prompts in a row (canceling through pressing escape), and then it starts working properly again.

These are the errors I get in the console when it has been canceled:
[image: Error messages]
I suspect one of the following, but really I have no idea:

1. Webpack is not configured correctly
2. There is some resource that requires authentication (but I can't figure out which), I am running everything on localhost
3. There is something wrong with the node.js server thingy...

Any tips on what might be going on are very welcome.

**Edit:** My backend is mocked in localhost.

**Edit 2:** I found this: [Receiving login prompt using integrated windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402381/receiving-login-prompt-using-integrated-windows-authentication) and it is possible that the thing that is causing the error is some faulty configuration in my IIS. But it is difficult to verify since it only shows up randomly.

Comment: 401 errors won't hide themselves from IIS log files, so you should be able to check. Focus on their sub-status codes and the cause should be clear, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Answer (score 1):

Webpack has nothing to do with your API calls.

401 errors are due to auth credentials failing.
It means that your backend ask you to update your token(s) used for auth in API calls.

Comment: My backend is mocked in localhost.

Comment: The route asks for auth anyway. Check your mock/http server